# How to append Date and time at the end using winston logger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I have winston logger that is logging events to `logs/server.log` and when it rotates files it creates `server20170321114031.log` because of date format but i want to rotate file in this format `server.log.20170321114031` and  current logging file name should always be `server.log` is it possible to achieve using winston ?

winston.js

```
logger = new (winston.Logger)({
            level: null,
            transports: [
//                new (winston.transports.Console)(),
                new (winston.transports.File)({
                    filename: './logs/server.log',
                    maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 20,//15728640 is 15 MB
                    timestamp: false,
                    json: false,
                    rotationFormat: function() {
                        return getFormattedDate();
                        function getFormattedDate() {
                          var temp = new Date();
                          return dateStr = padStr(temp.getFullYear()) +
                          padStr(1 + temp.getMonth()) +
                          padStr(temp.getDate()) +
                          padStr(temp.getHours()) +
                          padStr(temp.getMinutes()) +
                          padStr(temp.getSeconds());
                        }
                        function padStr(i) {
                          return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : "" + i;
                        }
                      },
                    formatter: function (options) {
                        return options.message;
                    }
                })
            ]
        });
```

Comment: While I can't answer this directly, you can modify the format of the log line by using [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node)

Comment: Couldn't you just remove this line? `timestamp: false,`

Comment: I can remove it but how it is related to question i asked ?

Comment: What value did you get from this?

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/pull/205

```
logger.configure({
  category1: {
    dailyRotateFile: {
      colorize: 'true',
      filename: 'dailyRotateFile.log',
      datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd',
      maxsize: 20000
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: i am not using dailyRotate File and my approach is different if you see my question ,